# How to make Stop and Pause/Resume/Play music buttons in Inno Setup

Tags: button, inno-setup, playback, pause

I want to create two buttons adjacent to each-other at the bottom left corner of all the pages like reloaded.

The first button shows the *Pause* and the *Resume* command (if I click *Pause*, the button will switch to *Resume* automatically).

The other button shows the *Stop* command (if I click *Stop*, the next button will switch to *Play from start* automatically)

This code just adds *Pause*/Resume/Play from start* button and *Stop* button

**The problem is: If I press *Stop* button, the music stops permanently and the *Play form start* button never appears.**

```pascal
    [Setup]
AppName=Bass Audio Project
AppVersion=1.0
DefaultDirName={pf}\Bass Audio Project

[Files]
Source: Bass.dll; Flags: dontcopy
Source: AudioFile.mp3; Flags: dontcopy


[Code]
const
  BASS_SAMPLE_LOOP = 4;
  BASS_ACTIVE_STOPPED = 0;
  BASS_ACTIVE_PLAYING = 1;
  BASS_ACTIVE_STALLED = 2;
  BASS_ACTIVE_PAUSED  = 3;
  BASS_UNICODE = $80000000;
  BASS_CONFIG_GVOL_STREAM = 5;
const
  #ifndef UNICODE
    EncodingFlag = 0;
  #else
    EncodingFlag = BASS_UNICODE;
  #endif
type
  HSTREAM = DWORD;

function BASS_Init(device: LongInt; freq, flags: DWORD;
  win: HWND; clsid: Cardinal): BOOL;
  external 'BASS_Init@files:bass.dll stdcall';
function BASS_StreamCreateFile(mem: BOOL; f: string; offset1: DWORD;
  offset2: DWORD; length1: DWORD; length2: DWORD; flags: DWORD): HSTREAM;
  external 'BASS_StreamCreateFile@files:bass.dll stdcall';
function BASS_Start: BOOL;
  external 'BASS_Start@files:bass.dll stdcall';
function BASS_Pause: BOOL;
  external 'BASS_Pause@files:bass.dll stdcall';
function BASS_Stop(): Boolean;
  external 'BASS_Stop@files:BASS.dll stdcall delayload';
function BASS_ChannelPlay(handle: DWORD; restart: BOOL): BOOL;
  external 'BASS_ChannelPlay@files:bass.dll stdcall';
function BASS_SetConfig(option: DWORD; value: DWORD ): BOOL;
  external 'BASS_SetConfig@files:bass.dll stdcall';
function BASS_ChannelIsActive(handle: DWORD): DWORD;
  external 'BASS_ChannelIsActive@files:bass.dll stdcall';
function BASS_Free: BOOL;
  external 'BASS_Free@files:bass.dll stdcall';

var
  SoundStream: HSTREAM;
  PauseResumePlayButton: TNewButton;
  StopButton: TNewButton;

procedure ResumeButtonClick(Sender: TObject); forward;

procedure PauseButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if BASS_Pause then
  begin
    PauseResumePlayButton.Caption := 'Resume';
    PauseResumePlayButton.OnClick := @ResumeButtonClick;
  end;
end;

procedure ResumeButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if BASS_start then
  begin
    PauseResumePlayButton.Caption := 'Pause';
    PauseResumePlayButton.OnClick := @PauseButtonClick;
  end;
end;

procedure PlayButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if BASS_Start then
  begin
    PauseResumePlayButton.Caption := 'Pause';
    PauseResumePlayButton.OnClick := @PauseButtonClick;
  end;
end;


procedure StopButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if BASS_Stop then
  begin
    PauseResumePlayButton.Caption := 'Play';
    PauseResumePlayButton.OnClick := @PlayButtonClick;
  end;
       begin
       BASS_Free;
       end;
end;

procedure InitializeWizard();
begin
  ExtractTemporaryFile('AudioFile.mp3');
  if BASS_Init(-1, 44100, 0, 0, 0) then
  begin
    SoundStream :=
      BASS_StreamCreateFile(
        False, ExpandConstant('{tmp}\AudioFile.mp3'), 0, 0, 0, 0,
        EncodingFlag or BASS_SAMPLE_LOOP);
    BASS_SetConfig(BASS_CONFIG_GVOL_STREAM, 2500);
    BASS_ChannelPlay(SoundStream, False);

    StopButton := TNewButton.Create(WizardForm);
    StopButton.Parent := WizardForm;
    StopButton.Left :=
      WizardForm.ClientWidth -
      WizardForm.CancelButton.Left - WizardForm.CancelButton.Width;
    StopButton.Top := WizardForm.CancelButton.Top;
    StopButton.Width :=  WizardForm.CancelButton.Width;
    StopButton.Height := WizardForm.CancelButton.Height;
    StopButton.Caption := 'Stop';
    StopButton.OnClick := @StopButtonClick;

    PauseResumePlayButton := TNewButton.Create(WizardForm);
    PauseResumePlayButton.Parent := WizardForm;
    PauseResumePlayButton.Left :=
      WizardForm.ClientWidth -
      WizardForm.NextButton.Left - WizardForm.NextButton.Width;
    PauseResumePlayButton.Top := WizardForm.CancelButton.Top;
    PauseResumePlayButton.Width :=  WizardForm.CancelButton.Width;
    PauseResumePlayButton.Height := WizardForm.CancelButton.Height;
    PauseResumePlayButton.Caption := 'Pause';
    PauseResumePlayButton.OnClick := @PauseButtonClick;
  end;
end;

procedure DeinitializeSetup;
begin
  BASS_Free;
end;
```

Comment: You cannot ask a specific user who has not participated in the thread to help. Be patient, and someone will help you when they can. If you can't wait, hire a contractor and pay them to figure it out for you. (It's always unclear to me why people want to play music from an installer - it's job is to **install software**, not to be a home entertainment center. You're introducing a dependency on Bass.DLL to be installed before your software, you're making the download much larger (wasting bandwidth), and making the install much slower, not even counting the extra work you're doing now.)

Comment: the  Bass.DLL is just a 33.5kb, not that much space.
and the download is indeed large so a few kilobytes additial to the gigantic files won't hurt.
the install would take at least 15 minutes to be installed, so it would be a good idea to play music during install

Comment: It also has to be installed first, and you have to include all of the sound files as well. You can play music by including a couple of small .wav files and play them using the Windows MMAPI without requiring an install. Users don't need to pause, rewind, start and stop sounds during an install - that turns your installer into a media player. You're doing the equivalent of creating paint to put on things as you throw them in the garbage - they won't be around but a few minutes, but boy will they be pretty while they last! Use your installer to install.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a good idea to implement this using a single `OnClick` handler.

Change the `OnClick` handler on the fly, as needed, for more straightforward code:

```pascal
const
  BASS_SAMPLE_LOOP = 4;
  BASS_ACTIVE_STOPPED = 0;
  BASS_ACTIVE_PLAYING = 1;
  BASS_ACTIVE_STALLED = 2;
  BASS_ACTIVE_PAUSED  = 3;
  BASS_UNICODE = $80000000;
  BASS_CONFIG_GVOL_STREAM = 5;
const
  #ifndef UNICODE
    EncodingFlag = 0;
  #else
    EncodingFlag = BASS_UNICODE;
  #endif
type
  HSTREAM = DWORD;

function BASS_Init(device: LongInt; freq, flags: DWORD;
  win: HWND; clsid: Cardinal): Boolean;
  external 'BASS_Init@files:bass.dll stdcall';
function BASS_StreamCreateFile(mem: Boolean; f: string; offset1: DWORD;
  offset2: DWORD; length1: DWORD; length2: DWORD; flags: DWORD): HSTREAM;
  external 'BASS_StreamCreateFile@files:bass.dll stdcall';
function BASS_ChannelPlay(handle: DWORD; restart: Boolean): Boolean;
  external 'BASS_ChannelPlay@files:bass.dll stdcall';
function BASS_ChannelPause(handle: DWORD): Boolean;
  external 'BASS_ChannelPause@files:bass.dll stdcall';
function BASS_SetConfig(option: DWORD; value: DWORD ): Boolean;
  external 'BASS_SetConfig@files:bass.dll stdcall';
function BASS_ChannelIsActive(handle: DWORD): DWORD;
  external 'BASS_ChannelIsActive@files:bass.dll stdcall';

var
  SoundStream: HSTREAM;
  PauseResumePlayButton: TNewButton;
  StopButton: TNewButton;

procedure ResumeButtonClick(Sender: TObject); forward;

procedure PauseButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if BASS_ChannelPause(SoundStream) then
  begin
    PauseResumePlayButton.Caption := 'Resume';
    PauseResumePlayButton.OnClick := @ResumeButtonClick;
  end;
end;  

procedure ResumeButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if BASS_ChannelPlay(SoundStream, False) then
  begin
    PauseResumePlayButton.Caption := 'Pause';
    PauseResumePlayButton.OnClick := @PauseButtonClick;
  end;
end;  

procedure PlayButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if BASS_ChannelPlay(SoundStream, True) then
  begin
    PauseResumePlayButton.Caption := 'Pause';
    PauseResumePlayButton.OnClick := @PauseButtonClick;
  end;
end;  

procedure StopButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if (BASS_ChannelIsActive(SoundStream) = BASS_ACTIVE_PAUSED) or
     BASS_ChannelPause(SoundStream) then
  begin
    PauseResumePlayButton.Caption := 'Play';
    PauseResumePlayButton.OnClick := @PlayButtonClick;
  end;
end;  

procedure InitializeWizard();
begin
  if BASS_Init(-1, 44100, 0, 0, 0) then
  begin
    ExtractTemporaryFile('AudioFile.mp3');
    SoundStream :=
      BASS_StreamCreateFile(
        False, ExpandConstant('{tmp}\AudioFile.mp3'), 0, 0, 0, 0,
        EncodingFlag or BASS_SAMPLE_LOOP);

    if SoundStream <> 0 then
    begin
      BASS_SetConfig(BASS_CONFIG_GVOL_STREAM, 2500);

      if BASS_ChannelPlay(SoundStream, False) then
      begin
        StopButton := TNewButton.Create(WizardForm);
        StopButton.Parent := WizardForm;
        StopButton.Left :=
          WizardForm.ClientWidth -
          WizardForm.CancelButton.Left -  WizardForm.CancelButton.Width;
        StopButton.Top := WizardForm.CancelButton.Top;
        StopButton.Width :=  WizardForm.CancelButton.Width;
        StopButton.Height := WizardForm.CancelButton.Height;
        StopButton.Caption := 'Stop';
        StopButton.OnClick := @StopButtonClick;

        PauseResumePlayButton := TNewButton.Create(WizardForm);
        PauseResumePlayButton.Parent := WizardForm;
        PauseResumePlayButton.Left :=
          WizardForm.ClientWidth -
          WizardForm.NextButton.Left -  WizardForm.NextButton.Width;
        PauseResumePlayButton.Top := WizardForm.CancelButton.Top;
        PauseResumePlayButton.Width :=  WizardForm.CancelButton.Width;
        PauseResumePlayButton.Height := WizardForm.CancelButton.Height;
        PauseResumePlayButton.Caption := 'Pause';
        PauseResumePlayButton.OnClick := @PauseButtonClick;
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

- Note that you called the `BASS_StreamCreateFile`, `BASS_SetConfig` and `BASS_ChannelPlay` twice with the same arguments. It does not make sense. I've removed the second set.
- I've also tweaked placement of the buttons.

[image: Music control buttons]

Comment: the ResumeButtonClick is not the problem it's StopButtonClick if i click stop button,  the music stops and then runs instantly whiteout clicking on the play button  **see my updated code**

Comment: Well, becase your `StopButtonClick` does not do what my answer shows. You call `BASS_Play`, so you cannot be surprised that your stop button starts playing.

Comment: so how to change that?
**what i want to do is this:
if i click stop button, the music won't play unless i click play button**
help please

Comment: So use the code from my answer! It does what you ask for!

Comment: no. if i click play after i click stop ,
the song won't start form the beginning
compare my updated code with yours and you will see that the pause/resume is not working properly, and the stop button wont't start the song after i click play button

Comment: I do not understand you. Sorry. I give up.

Comment: can you compile the code, and you will understand what i mean?

Comment: OK, I now understand what you mean, before you used your wrong code, but now you refer to my code. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
function BASS_ChannelPlay(handle: DWORD; restart: Boolean): Boolean;
  external 'BASS_ChannelPlay@files:bass.dll stdcall';
function BASS_ChannelPause(handle: DWORD): Boolean;
  external 'BASS_ChannelPause@files:bass.dll stdcall';
function BASS_ChannelIsActive(handle: DWORD): DWORD;
  external 'BASS_ChannelIsActive@files:bass.dll stdcall';

procedure MusicButtonOnClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if (BASS_ChannelIsActive(SoundStream) = 3)
 then
  BASS_ChannelPlay(SoundStream, False)
 else
  BASS_ChannelPause(SoundStream) 
end;
```

and on the button.OnClick add like this :

```
  YourButtonName.OnClick := @MusicButtonOnClick;
```