# Music glitches when exiting Inno Setup installer

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

I've used Martin Prikryl's code for my Inno Setup project. This is the link to his code:
[How to make Stop and Pause/Resume/Play music buttons in Inno Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39365779/how-to-make-stop-and-pause-resume-play-music-buttons-in-inno-setup)

I used it with some tweaks on it but the problem is that the music glitches when I finish it.

For example, if the music is working while installing something and when I finally finish the setup, I still hear the glitched Audio for about 3 seconds! It's very annoying!

I think the problem is that we need to unload Music dll's before the installer finishes, as we do with the skin.

I hope you understood my situation and thanks in advance!

This is my full code (it's not well-arranged sorry) :

```pascal
[Code]
{ RedesignWizardFormBegin } // Don't remove this line!
// Don't modify this section. It is generated automatically.
var
  OldEvent_NextButtonClick: TNotifyEvent;
  OldEvent_BackButtonClick: TNotifyEvent;
  Password: TNewStaticText;
  Website: TNewButton;

procedure _NextButtonClick(Sender: TObject); forward;
procedure _BackButtonClick(Sender: TObject); forward;
procedure PasswordClick(Sender: TObject); forward;
procedure Website1Click(Sender: TObject); forward;

procedure RedesignWizardForm;
begin
  with WizardForm.NextButton do
  begin
    OldEvent_NextButtonClick := OnClick;
    OnClick := @_NextButtonClick;
  end;

  with WizardForm.BackButton do
  begin
    OldEvent_BackButtonClick := OnClick;
    OnClick := @_BackButtonClick;
  end;

  with WizardForm.WizardBitmapImage do
  begin
    Left := ScaleX(1);
    Width := ScaleX(492);
    Height := ScaleY(313);
    Visible := False;
  end;

  with WizardForm.WelcomeLabel2 do
  begin
    Enabled := False;
    ParentShowHint := False;
    Visible := False;
    Left := ScaleX(96);
    Top := ScaleY(111);
    Width := ScaleX(69);
    Height := ScaleY(47);
  end;

  with WizardForm.WelcomeLabel1 do
  begin
    Enabled := False;
    ParentShowHint := False;
    Visible := False;
    Left := ScaleX(96);
    Top := ScaleY(71);
    Width := ScaleX(109);
    Height := ScaleY(39);
  end;

  with WizardForm.PasswordEdit do
  begin
    Hint := 'Write wave4tech';
    CharCase := ecLowerCase;
    ParentShowHint := False;
    Password := False;
    ShowHint := True;
  end;

  { Password }
  Password := TNewStaticText.Create(WizardForm);
  with Password do
  begin
    Name := 'Password';
    Parent := WizardForm.PasswordPage;
    Cursor := crHand;
    Caption := ' PASSWORD IS : wave4tech ';
    Color := clGrayText;
    Font.Color := clWhite;
    Font.Height := -16;
    Font.Name := 'Tahoma';
    Font.Style := [fsBold];
    ParentColor := False;
    ParentFont := False;
    ParentShowHint := False;
    ShowHint := False;
    OnClick := @PasswordClick;
    Left := ScaleX(0);
    Top := ScaleY(80);
    Width := ScaleX(232);
    Height := ScaleY(20);
  end;

  Password.TabOrder := 3;

  with WizardForm.WizardBitmapImage2 do
  begin
    Height := ScaleY(312);
    ExtractTemporaryFile('WizardForm.WizardBitmapImage2.bmp');
    Bitmap.LoadFromFile(ExpandConstant('{tmp}\WizardForm.WizardBitmapImage2.bmp'));
  end;

  { Website }
  Website := TNewButton.Create(WizardForm);
  with Website do
  begin
    Name := 'Website';
    Parent := WizardForm;
    Left := ScaleX(153);
    Top := ScaleY(327);
    Width := ScaleX(75);
    Height := ScaleY(23);
    OnClick := @Website1Click;
  end;

  Website.TabOrder := 5;

{ ReservationBegin }
  // This part is for you. Add your specialized code here.

{ ReservationEnd }
end;
// Don't modify this section. It is generated automatically.
{ RedesignWizardFormEnd } // Don't remove this line!

procedure PasswordClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
MsgBox('The Password of this Setup is based on our Website Name. Its wave4tech in SMALL LETTERS !!', mbInformation, mb_Ok);
end;

procedure _BackButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  OldEvent_BackButtonClick(Sender);
end;

procedure _NextButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  OldEvent_NextButtonClick(Sender);
end;

// Importing Browser Identifier
procedure OpenBrowser(Url: string);
var
  ErrorCode: Integer;
begin
  ShellExec('open', Url, '', '', SW_SHOWNORMAL, ewNoWait, ErrorCode);
end;

// Website Button Link
procedure Website1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
OpenBrowser('https://wave4technology.blogspot.com/');
end;

// Importing LoadSkin API from ISSkin.DLL
procedure LoadSkin(lpszPath: String; lpszIniFileName: String);
external 'LoadSkin@files:isskin.dll stdcall';

// Importing UnloadSkin API from ISSkin.DLL
procedure UnloadSkin();
external 'UnloadSkin@files:isskin.dll stdcall';

// Importing ShowWindow Windows API from User32.DLL
function ShowWindow(hWnd: Integer; uType: Integer): Integer;
external 'ShowWindow@user32.dll stdcall';

function InitializeSetup(): Boolean;
begin
    ExtractTemporaryFile('VZ_Green.cjstyles');
    LoadSkin(ExpandConstant('{tmp}\VZ_Green.cjstyles'), '');
    Result := True;
end;

procedure DeinitializeSetup();
begin
  // Hide Window before unloading skin so user does not get
  // a glimpse of an unskinned window before it is closed.
  ShowWindow(StrToInt(ExpandConstant('{wizardhwnd}')), 0);
  UnloadSkin();
end;

// Music Stop-Pause/Resume
const
  BASS_SAMPLE_LOOP = 4;
  BASS_ACTIVE_STOPPED = 0;
  BASS_ACTIVE_PLAYING = 1;
  BASS_ACTIVE_STALLED = 2;
  BASS_ACTIVE_PAUSED  = 3;
  BASS_UNICODE = $80000000;
  BASS_CONFIG_GVOL_STREAM = 5;
const
  #ifndef UNICODE
    EncodingFlag = 0;
  #else
    EncodingFlag = BASS_UNICODE;
  #endif
type
  HSTREAM = DWORD;

function BASS_Init(device: LongInt; freq, flags: DWORD;
  win: HWND; clsid: Cardinal): Boolean;
  external 'BASS_Init@files:bass.dll stdcall';
function BASS_StreamCreateFile(mem: Boolean; f: string; offset1: DWORD;
  offset2: DWORD; length1: DWORD; length2: DWORD; flags: DWORD): HSTREAM;
  external 'BASS_StreamCreateFile@files:bass.dll stdcall';
function BASS_ChannelPlay(handle: DWORD; restart: Boolean): Boolean;
  external 'BASS_ChannelPlay@files:bass.dll stdcall';
function BASS_ChannelPause(handle: DWORD): Boolean;
  external 'BASS_ChannelPause@files:bass.dll stdcall';
function BASS_SetConfig(option: DWORD; value: DWORD ): Boolean;
  external 'BASS_SetConfig@files:bass.dll stdcall';
function BASS_ChannelIsActive(handle: DWORD): DWORD;
  external 'BASS_ChannelIsActive@files:bass.dll stdcall';

var
  SoundStream: HSTREAM;
  PauseResumePlayButton: TNewButton;
  StopButton: TNewButton;

procedure ResumeButtonClick(Sender: TObject); forward;

procedure PauseButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if BASS_ChannelPause(SoundStream) then
  begin
    PauseResumePlayButton.Caption := 'Resume';
    PauseResumePlayButton.OnClick := @ResumeButtonClick;
  end;
end;

procedure ResumeButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if BASS_ChannelPlay(SoundStream, False) then
  begin
    PauseResumePlayButton.Caption := 'Pause';
    PauseResumePlayButton.OnClick := @PauseButtonClick;
  end;
end;

procedure PlayButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if BASS_ChannelPlay(SoundStream, True) then
  begin
    PauseResumePlayButton.Caption := 'Pause';
    PauseResumePlayButton.OnClick := @PauseButtonClick;
  end;
end;

procedure StopButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if (BASS_ChannelIsActive(SoundStream) = BASS_ACTIVE_PAUSED) or
     BASS_ChannelPause(SoundStream) then
  begin
    PauseResumePlayButton.Caption := 'Play';
    PauseResumePlayButton.OnClick := @PlayButtonClick;
  end;
end;

// Splash Code 1
procedure ShowSplashScreen(p1:HWND;p2:string;p3,p4,p5,p6,p7:integer;p8:boolean;p9:Cardinal;p10:integer); external 'ShowSplashScreen@files:isgsg.dll stdcall delayload';

procedure InitializeWizard();
begin
  // Splash Code 2
  ExtractTemporaryFile('Splash.png');
  ShowSplashScreen(WizardForm.Handle,ExpandConstant('{tmp}\Splash.png'),1000,3000,1000,0,255,True,$FFFFFF,10);
  
  RedesignWizardForm;
  with WizardForm.WizardBitmapImage do
  begin
    Width := ScaleX(492);
    Visible := True;
  end;

  with WizardForm.WelcomeLabel2 do
  begin
    Visible := False;
  end;

  with WizardForm.WelcomeLabel1 do
  begin
    Visible := False;
  end;
  if BASS_Init(-1, 44100, 0, 0, 0) then
  begin
    ExtractTemporaryFile('AudioFile.mp3');
    SoundStream :=
      BASS_StreamCreateFile(
        False, ExpandConstant('{tmp}\AudioFile.mp3'), 0, 0, 0, 0,
        EncodingFlag or BASS_SAMPLE_LOOP);

    if SoundStream <> 0 then
    begin
      BASS_SetConfig(BASS_CONFIG_GVOL_STREAM, 2500);

      if BASS_ChannelPlay(SoundStream, False) then
      begin
        StopButton := TNewButton.Create(WizardForm);
        StopButton.Parent := WizardForm;
        StopButton.Left :=
          WizardForm.ClientWidth -
          WizardForm.CancelButton.Left -  WizardForm.CancelButton.Width;
        StopButton.Top := WizardForm.CancelButton.Top;
        StopButton.Width :=  WizardForm.CancelButton.Width;
        StopButton.Height := WizardForm.CancelButton.Height;
        StopButton.Caption := 'Stop Music';
        StopButton.OnClick := @StopButtonClick;

        PauseResumePlayButton := TNewButton.Create(WizardForm);
        PauseResumePlayButton.Parent := WizardForm;
        PauseResumePlayButton.Left := ScaleX(80);
        PauseResumePlayButton.Top := ScaleY(327);
        PauseResumePlayButton.Width := ScaleX(75);
        PauseResumePlayButton.Height := ScaleY(23);
        PauseResumePlayButton.Caption := 'Pause Music';
        PauseResumePlayButton.OnClick := @PauseButtonClick;
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: If you insist on this approach, you should definitely give the user the option of whether they want to start the music or not. In my opinion you should not start playing music without asking (the "not asking the user" part is the annoyance, not whether you like the music or not).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to stop the music, when the installer is closing, just use the same code you *already have* in `StopButtonClick` from `DeinitializeSetup`:

```pascal
procedure DeinitializeSetup();
begin
  if (SoundStream <> 0) and
     (BASS_ChannelIsActive(SoundStream) <> BASS_ACTIVE_PAUSED) then
  begin
    BASS_ChannelPause(SoundStream);
  end;

  // Hide Window before unloading skin so user does not get
  // a glimpse of an unskinned window before it is closed.
  ShowWindow(StrToInt(ExpandConstant('{wizardhwnd}')), 0);
  UnloadSkin();
end;
```

Comment: ohh didn't even think about it thank you so much sir love from Turkey 